# getting sign of LP solution variables

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I have an LP where I'm only interested in the sign of some of the variables of an optimal solution. The value itself does not matter.

Currently I'm using cplex to get an optimal solution and take the signs from there.

However, the LP is rather big so I wonder if there is a way/algorithm to obtain the signs without the need of finding an optimal solution?

Comment: How large is this LP?

Comment: Around 100000 to 150000 variable. For me, the problem is that it is part of an iterative algorithm and I try to reduce the time of each iteration since there are many of them.

Comment: I'd be curious to hear more about the structure of your problem.  Also, since this is part of an iterative algorithm, I wonder if a "warm start" would be helpful, using the solution from the previous iteration as an initial guess for the current iteration.

Comment: In every iteration, I'm changing multiple entries in the coefficient matrix and then run cplex again. I assume/hope that cplex uses a warm start. I investigate the structure of the problem to find a more natural algorithm but I hopped that there might be some theory already out there.

Answer (score 1):

One possible option, which may be more hindrance than helpful, is to introduce additional binary variables.

Suppose your variables are $x_i$, $M$ is an arbitrarily large number and $y_i$ is binary.

Inclusion of the constraints
$$\begin{align}
x_i&\leq My_i\\
-x_i&\leq M(1-y_i)
\end{align}$$
will set $y_i=1$ if $x_i>0$ and $y_i=0$ if $x_i<0$. In the case $x_i=0$, then $y_i$ could be either $0$ or $1$.

The downside is that this doubles the number of decision variables, adds a number of constraints and forces an IP solver, rather than simply an LP solver.

Comment: I do not understand how this helps to solve the problem faster. Solving the MIP is slower and I can obtain the signs from the LP without the use of the binary variables.

Comment: @Stan I prefaced this by saying it may be more hindrance than helpful. It could be argued that, if your MIP solver uses a branch and bound approach, you know from the branching, before any solution is reached, if the variable being branched on is positive or negative. i.e. If you branch on $y_i$, this branching is equivalent to adding the restrictions $x_i\leq0$ in one subproblem and $x_i\geq0$ in the other. This can eliminate a number of possibilities quickly. All this said, you are doubling the number of DV, which is usually a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost positive the answer is no unless your LP has some very special form that you can deduce the signs by inspection; I took an entire course on LP and never heard anything about being able to "predict" the signs of an LP solution easily without solving the LP.